# cannot find monkeyrunner file after installing android SDK and downloading command line tools

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, monkeyrunner

I am trying to use monkeyrunner on linux system. However, I am unable to locate monkeyrunner file.

I have installed andriod studio using this link https://developer.android.com/studio/, android studio running fine and i'm able to create adroid virtual machine. I have also downloaded and extracted command line tools from this link https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools.

From all the resources on internet that I have seen, they say that monkeyrunner will be in tools/bin folder, however, this is not the case. I have downloaded tools for windows and mac as well but even these don't have monkeyrunner in tools/bin folder. tools/bin has only following four files

> apkanalyzer  avdmanager  lint  screenshot2  sdkmanager

I have also searched all the  files on my linux system to find a file or folder named moneyrunner without any luck.

Can anyone please help me in figuring this out?

Comment: I was also trying to use monkeyrunner to script some touchscreen motions. I think it is deprecated: after many wasted hours I downloaded an old sdk (from 2015) and monkeyrunner was there; however (as expected) it doesn't run out of the box, maybe it needs an older version of java and some othere stuff... For me it wasn't worth the truble so I stopped trying. If you really need it and you can't use a more modern tool you might try to use an old sdk (probably not a good idea though).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this.

The problem was that Android SDK Tools are obsolete (I am not sure since when as I cannot find any documentation on official website).

Unlike Android SDK Platform-Tools, Android SDK tools are not implicitly installed with installation of Android studio. However, can be installed explicitly after installing Android Studio, using following method:

1. Open Android Studio
2. click on "Configure" on bottom left corner
3. A window for "Settings for New Projects" will open, select "Android SDK" from left side menu
4. Select "SDK Tools" in middle panel
5. Uncheck "Hide Obsolete Packages" from bottom left
6. Now you will be able to see "Android SDK Tools (obsolete)", check it and click on Apply. It will then install Android SDK Tools
7. **monkeyrunner** will be `/Android/Sdk/tools/bin` folder

P.S. I also followed same steps for windows, and monkeyrunner was in `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin` folder, where `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android` is path where android studio was installed.